# How can I split two steps in one algorithm box for LaTeX?

Tags: algorithms

How can I split two steps in one algorithm box for LaTeX like below image?

Is it impossible? If possible, please answer me.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Are you tied to this output, or are you open to alternatives that might be more visually appealing? What are the restrictions in terms of packages?

Comment: I'm trying to reduce context due to letter's volume by tying two steps in one algorithm. I have no restrictions in terms of packages. I only want to solve this problem. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use `\Statex` from [`algpseudocode`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) to "comment" a step or break:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand{\And}{\textbf{and}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{A two-step algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Statex \textit{First step}
    \While{$X\ \And\ Y$}
      \State Statement~1
      \If{$Z$}
        \State Statement~2
      \EndIf
    \EndWhile
    \Statex \textit{Second step}
    \While{$Y\ \And\ X$}
      \State Statement~3
      \If{$Z$}
        \State Statement~4
      \EndIf
    \EndWhile
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here is a very simple adaptation that adds hrules above and below text: `\newcommand{\algstep}[1]{\item[]\medskip\hrule\kern 2pt\hbox to \textwidth{\hspace{\labelsep}\textbf{#1}\hfill}\hrule}`